# How to fix Memory Leak in SBJSON file in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am having memory leak as shown below.

[image: NSObject+SBJSON.h file]

Please suggest how to fix below memory leak.

**Note**: I am using ARC in my Project.

Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: try go `jsonWriter = nil;` just before the return statement, but its kinda strange, it shouldnt be needed, maybe the analyser is confused

Comment: also maybe make sure in your project settings under compile sources the SBJsonWriter doesnt have the -fno-objc-arc flag set

Comment: ThanQ @Fonix that's fix the issue. In my project I have fno-objc-arc flag set to SBJSONWriter files...! Please add it as answer..

Comment: glad to hear, will add as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like arc is disabled in this case, see if the SBJSONWriter files under compiles sources in your project settings has the `-fno-objc-arc` flag set